# Greatest integer less than or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, contest-math

This is a PhD entrance question of TIFR 2020. The question requires the explicit answer. I know that the partial sums are evaluated using Abel's formula in Number Theory but I believe there may be better methods for series of this form. Can anyone share their thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Compare the sum with the appropriate definite integrals:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}>\int_1^{10000}\frac{dx}{x^{1/4}}=\frac{4}{3}x^{3/4}\bigg|_1^{10000}=\frac{4}{3}\cdot 999=1332$$

Also:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}
&< \sum_{n=1}^{10000}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}} \\
&= 1+\sum_{n=2}^{10000}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}} \\
&< 1+\int_1^{10000}\frac{dx}{x^{1/4}} \\
&= 1+\frac{4}{3}x^{3/4}\bigg|_1^{10000} \\
&= 1+\frac{4}{3}\cdot 999 \\
&=1333
\end{align}$$

So, the sum is between $1332$ and $1333$ and so its integral part is $1332$.

Comment: And the ultimate proof: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+1%2Fn%5E%281%2F4%29+when+n%3D1+to+10000 ;)

Comment: This may sound elementary, but when can we say that a summation is greater than an integral as you have done in the first step?

Comment: Draw the graph of the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}$ and then also draw the "bars" (like on the bar chart) between integers $n, n+1$ so that the height of each bar is $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$. Now compare the areas "under the curve" and "under the 'bar chart'" ;) on the range $1$ to $10,000$. This is the first inequality. The second one is similar, but the height of the bars is $\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/4}}$.

Comment: @Kashif Does this help: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/old-ap-calculus-bc/bc-series/bc-estimating-inf-series/v/integrals-estimating-p-series ? (Maybe there are better references, this one came up as the first sensible one in a Google search.)

Comment: "when can we say that a summation is greater than an integral" If for all $x \in [a,b]$, $f(x) \le c$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b cdx = c(b-a)$.  And on the interval $x\in [n, n+1]$ we have $\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} \le \frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$ so $\int_n^{n+1}\frac1{x^{\frac 14}}dx\le \frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$.  So $\sum_{n=1}^{999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}\le \sum_{n=1}^{999}\int_n^{n+1}\frac1{x^{\frac 14}}dx=\int_1^{1000} \frac1{x^{\frac 14}}dx$.

Comment: @fleablood Is your inequality pointing the wrong way in your last LaTeX expression? You previously say that integral is less than $\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$ but then in your last LaTeX expression you have that the sum is less than the integral?

Comment: I don't know.  probably.  I have a headache. .... yeah... as $n \le x$ then $\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} \le \frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$ so yes  The inequality should go the other way.  The sum is greater than the integer.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood This helped. These logics can be helpful for further problems of this type.

Comment: @fleabood. Can you please explain again as to when can we say that integral Is less than summation? Also why can we change definite summation to definite integral? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Consider the function $f(x):=\frac43\cdot x^{\frac34}$ and use the Mean Value Theorem in order to deduce that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{r+1}}=f'(r+1)<\frac{f(r+1)-f(r)}{r+1-r}<f'(r)=\frac1{\sqrt[4]{r}}\iff\fbox{$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{r+1}}< f(r+1)-f(r)<\frac1{\sqrt[4]{r}}$}$$ You can now sum and use the fact that almost everything will telescope.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to consider stinking Bishops answer.  This is a derivative answer and the exact same as Stinking Bishop's.  I'm just squinting and looking at it from a different angle.

> $c_1=\frac 1{(n+1)^{\frac 14}} \le \frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} \le \frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}=c_2$

> $c_1 \le \inf_{x\in [n,n+1]}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} \le \sup_{x\in [n,n+1]}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} \le c_2$

> $\int_{n}^{n+1} c_1dx \le \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}}dx \le \int_n^{n+1} c_2 dx$

Now $\int_a^b C dx = C[b-a]$ so $\int_{n}^{n+1} c_1dx=c_1= \frac 1{(n+1)^{\frac 14}}$ and  $\int_n^{n+1} c_2 dx=\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$ so

> $\frac 1{(n+1)^{\frac 14}}= \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}}dx \le \frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$

> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{(n+1)^{\frac 14}}\le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999} \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}}dx=\int_1^{10000}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} dx\le  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$

As noted $\int_1^{10000}\frac 1{x^{\frac 14}} dx= 1332$

But also note

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{(n+1)^{\frac 14}}$ may be reindexed as $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{10000}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$ which is equal to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}} + \frac 1{10000^{\frac 14}} - \frac 1{1^{\frac 14}}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}- 0.9$.

So we have

> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}- 0.9\le 1332 \le \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}$

And it is easily verified that if $M - 1< M-0.9 \le n \le M$ then $M< n+1 \le M+1$ and so $n\le M< n+1$ so $\lfloor M\rfloor=n$.

> So $\lfloor \sum\limits_{n=1}^{9999}\frac 1{n^{\frac 14}}\rfloor =1332$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212952/a-question-related-to-greatest-integer-less-than-or-equal-to-sum-n-19999)