# A question related to Greatest integer less than or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation

This question has answers here [Greatest integer less than or equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794174/greatest-integer-less-than-or-equal-to-sum-n-19999-frac1n1-4) but I'm posting the same question because I did not understand the answer given by @fleablood to " how can we know summation is greater than integral?" asked by the original person who posted the question. I would've asked there, but it is an old post. Also, how can we change summation to definite integral as done in this answer.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can leave a comment there, under fleablood's answer.

Comment: I thought he/she wouldn't see or answer? I will edit the question.

Comment: They are still active, and will be notified then someone leave a comment.

Comment: Okk I will ask there as well. Thanks

Comment: @NatashaJ Other users can answer your questions in the comments as well.

Comment: I asked the question there as well. Thank you